# How can I add elements in JS to certain divs

Tags: javascript, html

How do I put the created input into the other div in situation I presented below? If I introduce divs in js like this - `'<div class="monday_input"><input type="button" class="remove_button" value="-" onclick="removeMon(this)" /></div>'` removing the whole element is not working for some reason in this specific case. Answering the question. No I cannot create div in parent in html because input won't magically suit to created div . Please help me somehow, thank you!

HTML:

```
<div class="day">
        <div class="day_info">
            <p>Monday</p>
        </div>
        <div class="add">
            <div class="button" onclick="add_monday()">
                <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mon">
    
    
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

Function to adding:

```js
function add_monday() {
    if (monday_sub_count < 5) {
        monday_sub_count++;
        {
            const mon = document.createElement('div');

            mon.className = 'subcategory';

            mon.innerHTML = '<textarea name="monday'+monday_id_count+'" placeholder="Type anything you want here" class="subcategory_text"></textarea><input type="button" class="remove_button" value="-" onclick="removeMon(this)" />';

            monday_id_count++;

            document.getElementById('mon').appendChild(mon);
        }
    }
}
```

Function to removing:

```
function removeMon(mon) {
    document.getElementById('mon').removeChild(mon.parentNode);
    monday_sub_count--;
    monday_id_count--;
};
```

Comment: Please add your css to create a [mre]!

Comment: Also, whats the point of the `{` after `monday_sub_count++;` ?

Answer (score 0):

with your own HTML

```
function add_monday() {
            var monday_sub_count = 0;
            var a;
            while (monday_sub_count < 5) {
                a = '<div><textarea name="monday'+monday_id_count+'" placeholder="Type anything you want here" class="subcategory_text"></textarea><input type="button" class="remove_button" value="-" onclick="removeMon(this)" /></div>';
                    monday_sub_count++;
                $('#mon').append(a);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working, "proper" version of your code. I think your problem may come from over-complicating the removal process.

```
function add_monday()
{
    let monday_count = 0;
    // Use DocumentFragment for marginal optimizations
    let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
    while(monday_count < 5)
    {
        let monday = document.createElement('div');
            monday.classList.add('subcategory');
        let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
            textarea.classList.add('subcategory_text');
            textarea.name = "monday_"+monday_count;
            textarea.placeholder = "Type anything you want here";
        let removeBtn = document.createElement('input');
            removeBtn.type = "button";
            removeBtn.classList.add('remove_button');
            removeBtn.value = "-";
            removeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeMon.bind(null, removeBtn));
        
        monday.append(textarea, removeBtn);

        fragment.appendChild(monday);
        monday_count++;
    }

    document.getElementById('mon').appendChild(fragment);
}

function removeMon(button)
{
    button.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: But how do I belong this input, which is 'removeBtn' in your code to ANOTHER div. I meant to do something like this '<div class="subcategory"><div class="monday_input"><input type="button" class="remove_button" value="-" onclick="removeMon(this)" /></div></div>'. This is child div in parent div right

Comment: And textarea as well

Comment: @TurboAsker I'm sorry, but I'm having troubles understanding. Say you have `monday_1`, `monday_2`, `monday_3`, etc. Are you saying you want the `remove_button` in `monday_1` to remove the `monday_2` div, or the `monday_1` div?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your script a little and changed your `name` attributes: Instead of assigning individual names I simply gave all textareas the name `monday[]`. When posting this to a PHP page the values will be pushed into an array with the same name and in case you want to harvest the values with JavaScript, then this can be done easily too.

```js
function add_monday(){
  $("#mon").append('<div><textarea name="monday[]" placeholder="Type anything you want here"></textarea><input type="button" value="-"/></div>'.repeat(5))
}
$("#mon").on("click","input[type=button]",function(){$(this).parent(). remove()})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="day">
    <div class="day_info">
        <p>Monday</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add">
        <div class="button" onclick="add_monday()">
            <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus">click here to add fields</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="mon">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

And here a non-jQuery version:

```js
const ad=document.querySelector(".alldays");
ad.innerHTML=
 "Mon,Tues,Wednes,Thurs,Fri,Satur,Sun".split(",").map(d=>`
<div class="day">
 <div class="day_info"><p>${d}day</p></div>
 <div class="add">
  <div class="button">
   <i class="fas fa-plus" id="plus">click here to add fields</i>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="${d.toLowerCase().substr(0,3)}">
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>`).join("");

function add2day(el,n){
 const wd=el.closest(".day"),
   d=wd.querySelector("p").textContent.toLowerCase(),
   html=`<textarea name="${d.toLowerCase()}[]" placeholder="Type anything you want here"></textarea><input type="button" value="-"/>`;
 while (n--) {
  let div= document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML=html;
  wd.nextElementSibling.appendChild(div);
 }
}

ad.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
 const el=ev.target;
 switch(el.tagName){
  case "INPUT": // remove field
   el.parentNode.remove(); break;
  case "I":     // add new fields
   add2day(el,3); break;
 }
})
```

```html
<div class="alldays"></div>
```

I extended the second script to make it work for any day of the week.